# Get error: Cannot implicitly convert type in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<TvApi.Data.TvMazeContext>' to 'TvApi.Data.TvMazeContext' TvApi

Something is wrong in this part `db = context` of my controller but I don't know how to solve:

```cs
public ShowsController(ILogger<ShowsController> logger, DbContextOptions<TvMazeContext> context)
{
    _logger = logger;
    db = context;
}
```

This is my controller:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TvApi.Data;
using TvApi.Models;

namespace TvApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ShowsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ShowsController> _logger;
        private readonly TvMazeContext db;

        public ShowsController(ILogger<ShowsController> logger, DbContextOptions<TvMazeContext> context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            db = context;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.shows.ToListAsync());
        }

    }
}
```

My DbContext:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TvApi.Models;

namespace TvApi.Data
{
    public class TvMazeContext : DbContext
    {
        public TvMazeContext(DbContextOptions<TvMazeContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Show> shows { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cast> casts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShowCast> showCasts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Show>().ToTable("Show");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Cast>().ToTable("Cast");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowCast>().ToTable("ShowCast");
        }

    }
}
```

My program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TvApi.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

//Database
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TvMazeContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        TvMazeContext dbcontext = (TvMazeContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(TvMazeContext));
        await DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(dbcontext);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var Logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TvMazeContext>>();
        Logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured creating the DB");
    }

}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

What am I doing wrong that causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `DbContextOptions<TvMazeContext>` in the constructor, use `TvMazeContext` as the injected service in which you have registered the `TvMazeContext` in the *Program.cs*.

```cs
public ShowsController(ILogger<ShowsController> logger, TvMazeContext context)
{
    _logger = logger;
    db = context;
}
```